# How to avoid or perform Cross domain $.get when using ISA

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, cross-domain, cross-domain-proxy

I have the ajax query

```
    var url = "http://ISAServer.domain.com/WebSite";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Load Successful');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.readyState);
            console.log(data.status);
            console.log(data.statusText);
            console.log(data.responseText);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

The error callback is called.  In order to go through ISA, I use an IPad.  Using an IPad, the values returned are not very helpful.

- [object Object]
- 0
- 0
- error
- ""

I am fairly sure the issue is a cross domain get request.  ISA somehow should redirect me to

"http://internal.domain/WebSite"

But it fails.  Things are fine when I do not go through ISA and also make a `$.get` request from the same domain (fails if I try cross domain, like localhost to server).

I am using ASP.NET MVC-3.  I have been unsuccessful implementing relative URL's.  They end up in the form

"http://servername/siteName/Controller/ControllerService?query"

When it should be

"http://servername/siteName/ControllerService?query"

So, unless you know how to fix that, relative URL's are not an option (and being we have to go through ISA I seriously doubt it would solve anything).  I have a helper method which resolves the current path "http://servername/siteName".

Any tips, ideas suggestions?

Comment: We solved the issue by having the same domain name inside and outside.  company.com/site is used internally and externally.  DNS just resolves to different IP addresses.  I'll leave the question open for a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform cross-domain ajax requests. Well, there are ways to do it, but the built-in library doesn't allow for it for security reasons.

http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/ provides a method to do this. I can't vouch for it, as I've never tried it, though.

From the URL above, though: "In client-side javascript, this functionality is not present due to the Same Origin Policy. Though this policy is necessary for a robust security model, programmers are often handicapped in their wish to send and retrieve requests to remote servers."